# Bash non-null/non-zero check multiple string variables

Tags: bash

I am trying to check if multiple command line arguments are set. Eg.

```
if [-n "$1"] && [-n "$2"] && [-n "$3"]; then
   do something
else
   do something else
fi
```

But I keep getting

> bash: [-n: command not found

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need spaces between the braces, i.e.

```
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ] && [ -n "$3" ]; then
```

You can also use [extended test command (`[[...]]`)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) as

```
if [[ -n "$1" && -n "$2" && -n "$3" ]]; then
```

Comment: wow I wouldn't have spotted that one thanks! will accept when it lets me

Comment: @PaulStatham: You can always use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to debug such syntax issues in the future.